# How to change screen on a tap, in Android?

Tags: android, tap

I have a really simple Android Application - pretty much the most simple possible.

I have two different `setContentView` calls. I want the second one to be called after the user taps on the screen. Everything works otherwise.

How do I get that view to pop up when the user taps?

Here is my `MainActivity` class:

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

And here is `activity_main2`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/corporatesplash" >

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What does activity_main2.xml look like? And I don't think your first setContentView does anything

Comment: "user taps on the screen" is not clear. please provide more information. what is the layout?

Answer (score 0):

So if I undestand correctly there is a button on your screen. If user clicks the button, the proper action is being called (sendMessage). If user clicks any area on screen apart from the button, the other thing is being called (setContentView or w/e). Is that correct?

If yes, I would advice you to create a View, that you would place under the Button, filling the screen (for example in RelativeLayout). And add to it a [OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html).

Comment: No that method was useless and empty, I just removed it

Comment: ... and more importantly: whats useless? whole approach or the OnTouchListener?

Answer (score 0):

you have to make one default contentview and the other

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                        if(firstTap){

                            firstTap = false;
                            reloadclass(); 
// use any method for reload the class i recommend to use intent and reload the class 
//and also use Put string through intent and set variable firsttap and 
//check if the click is first time or not

                        }
                        else
                        {
                                firstTap = true;


                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
```